# How to apply alternating-color table styles over cell styles in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't like the fact that Excel cells have no-fill by default. So I have edited the "Normal" cell styles to have white background. 
[White background color cell styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIWlN.png)

However, after doing this alternating color for structured tables don't work anymore. Apparently, cell styles will take priority over table styles.
[Table styles are overriden by cell styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RINKm.png)

While this is what I want the table styles to be:
[What I want for table styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5xR6.png)

Comment: If you select the table, and remove the color from it, it will get the style back and ignore future white cells when expanding.

Comment: What do you mean remove the color from it @ChristoferWeber

Answer (score 0):

As an elaboration of my comment, I made a small GIF of what I meant:

[image]

So when you have all the cells being white, you can select the table, pick "no fill" and then the table should go back to the normal style.

Your results may vary. I tried doing tables with normal set to white, and I don't even get the effect from the start:

[image]